# Finding multiple files from different folders using regular expressions

Tags: regex, r, file-upload

I'm trying to load multiple .txt files in R, from different folders.
I have problems writing the path and pattern using regular expressions.

My path has this structure:

```
'/Users/folderA/folderB/folderC/folderD/01_01_2012/folderE/file.txt'
```

So, the path is almost the same, except that the folder with the date name always changes.
I have tried to load it like this:

```
filesToProcess <- list.files(path = "/Users/folderA/folderB/folderC/folderD/", 
                             pattern = "*_*_*/folderE/*.txt")
```

But this doesn't seem to work.
Could someone please help me writing down this with regular expressions?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is to use argument `recursive=TRUE` so that you can search inside the folders that are in the original directory:

```
filesToProcess <- list.files(path = "/Users/folderA/folderB/folderC/folderD", 
                      pattern = "txt", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)
```

The pattern has to correspond to the name of the files, it can't refer to the name of the folders (see `?list.files`). That's why you need a second step where you have to narrow down to the specific folders you wanted. Note the use of argument `full.names=TRUE`in the previous call that allow us to keep the path of each file (NB: you also have to drop the final `/` of the `path` argument or else it ends up doubled in our output and leads to an error when you'll try to upload the files).

```
filesToProcess[grep("folderE", filesToProcess)]
```

A final note:
Your regular expression was flawed anyway: `*` means

> The preceding item will be matched zero or more times.

What you wanted was `.`: see `?regexp`

> The period . matches any single character.

Answer (score 0):

Although the subject refers to regular expressions it seems from the example that you really want to use globs.  In that case try:

```
Sys.glob("/Users/folderA/folderB/folderC/folderD/*_*_*/folderE/*.txt")
```